# How to reduce character from given String until it becomes to palindrome in java

Tags: java, string, palindrome

Here i have code to check whether given string is palindrome or not but don't know the procedure to reduce characters from last.To make change the character i need to follow the rule as: Eg `String input="abcde"`.Letter 'e' can be converted to 'd' but not 'e' to 'd' if character becomes 'a' we can't change further.Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "abcd";
    String temp = input;
    String output = "";
    for (int i = output.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output = output + output.charAt(i);
    }
    if(temp.equals(output)){
        System.out.println("String is palindrome");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

output order logic is as follows:

```
if input is =abcd
    abcc('d' converted to 'c')and check for palindrome
    abcb('c' converted to 'b')and check for palindrome
    abca('b' converted to 'a')and check for palindrome
    abba('a' further we can't change so shift to previous letter 'c' and change to 'b') 
          and check for palindrome

String is palindrome and count is=4

if input=cbdf
    cbde('f' converted to 'f')and check for palindrome
    cdbd('e' converted to 'd')and check for palindrome
    cdbc('d' converted to 'c')and check for palindrome
    cdbb('c' converted to 'b')and check for palindrome
    cdba('b' converted to 'a')and check for palindrome
    cdaa('a' further we can't change so shift to previous letter 'b' and change to 'a')
      and check for palindrome
    ccaa('a' further we can't change so shift to previous letter 'd' and change to 'c')
      and check for palindrome
    cbaa('c' converted to 'b')and check for palindrome
    caaa('a' further we can't change so shift to previous letter 'c' and change to 'b')
       and check for palindrome
    baaa('b' converted to 'a')and check for palindrome
    aaaa now string is palindrome
    String is palindrome and count is=10
   finally i need the count to make string palindrome.
```

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what the expected input and output is. As stated, this question is unclear. Add a few examples demonstrating the constraints of the problem.

Comment: As I understand it, the goal is to take a string S, and return another string T which is a palindrome, with the constraint that for all i, T[i] <= S[i]. Is this correct?

Comment: @AJMansfield,i have added the output order logic order at bottom of my question tag.and result should be number of times we changed character.that is 4.

Comment: Is this "The Love-Letter Mystery"?  If it is, you're not supposed to actually create the changed strings--you're supposed to think about how you could compute the number of changes needed, without actually doing them.  Unless someone else gave you some other requirements.

Comment: @ajb,yes that is The Love-Letter Mystery problem.for input string 'cbdf' result should be 10.I'm right?

Comment: @GangadharB no, it should be 5.

Comment: @ajb,could you please explain me how that will be 5 for string cbdf

Comment: @GangadharB see AJMansfield's comment below his answer.  That shows the 5 changes needed to turn `"cbdf"` into a palindrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I understand your problem, you are going about this in an inefficent way. Here is how I would do this:

```
String toPalindrome(String str){
    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(str).reverse();

    for(int idx = 0; idx < str.size()/2; idx++)
        if(str.getCharAt(idx) < reverse.getCharAt(idx))
            reverse.setCharAt(idx, str.getCharAt(idx));

    return reverse.subString(0,str.size()/2) + reverse.reverse().subString(str.size()/2);
}
```

Aside from the off-by-one errors in this code, this should work to produce the output you need.

Using this approach, we don't have to decrement each character one by one - we rather just immediately replace each character with the target value. We also never have to check if it is a palindrome, since this method is guaranteed to produce one (after all, it is concatenating a string with its mirror image in the return step).

EDIT: seeing that we need only return the number of times characters were decremented, we can do something even simpler:

```
int abs(int x){
    return x>0?x:-x;
}

int palindromeCounts(String str){
    int count = 0;

    for(int idx = 0; idx < str.length()/2; idx++)
        count += abs(str.charAt(idx) - reverse.charAt(str.length()-1-idx));

    return count;
}
```

Comment: AJMansfield,Could you please run your here http://ideone.com/ .I have updated my question and try to check once please..

Comment: I have run it and it works perfectly. It produces all the same answers as the sample output from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery. And it also produced the correct value for "cbdf", which is actually 5. (cbdf -> cbde -> cbdd -> cbdc -> cbcc -> cbbc)

Comment: AJMansfield,can you check for input cbdf output is coming as 5 but that is wrong it should be 10.and str.size i changed to str.length() and getChartAt() changed to charAt().

Comment: @GangadharB You are correct, I had some typos. You are wrong, the answer is 5. The challenge asks for the _minimum_ possible number of decrements to make it a palindrome.

Comment: AJMansfield,Could you please explain me how this code get output as 5.When i have shown in question for string 'cbdf' count will come 10.

Comment: With these five transformations you can make 'cbdf' palindromic: cbdf -> cbde -> cbdd -> cbdc -> cbcc -> cbbc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65731/discussion-between-ajmansfield-and-gangadhar-b).

Comment: AJMansfield,directly can we change 'e' to 'b'  in 'cbec' to 'cbbc' at last?

Comment: Yes, in fact that is what my code does: it takes the string, reverses it, and calculates how many places different the mirrored characters are from the originals.

Comment: AJMansfield,how to mark your updated answer,there is no option showing for that.

Comment: AJMansfield,thanks a lot for helping me to solve the problem.